# Best animal to record?

Tags: animals, recording, sound-design

Animals can be a great source for sound design with the great variety of calls, movement, breathing etc.

But what has been your favourite animal to record or is there an animal you just keep going back to for sound design?

Or do you just stick with the phrase 'don't work with children or animals'?

Answer (score 4):

I think Grizzly Bears have been my favorite.  It's like recording Chewbacca.

Answer (score 3):

I like to record my cat. Generally I like working with children. So I don't agree with phrase 'don't work with children or animals' :)

Answer (score 2):

I have recorded a lot of animals and my favorite was an adult leopard that was licking my hand and growling. Really great fun. Also birds can be great- the mariboo stork has a really interesting flap sound and can be used to sweeten in sound design. I am going into KwaZulu Natal this holiday and will be recording lots of animals, village ambiance, different South African wallas etc. Going to be fun.

Answer (score 2):

Baboons! Absolutely amazing to work with and interesting sounds.

Answer (score 2):

I just did a session with a surly cat named Cringer, and got some great sounds out of it.  I have a blog post about it you can find here - http://www.azimuthaudio.ca/
  At the end of the post there is a link to download "The Cringer Collection", 30 individual files of kitty vocalizations, with Soundminer Metadata.  Feel free to pull them down and add them to your library if you like.

Comment: @AzimuthAudio Nice sounds! Very expressive

Comment: Thanks @Filipe Chagas.  Hope they make themselves useful for you one day.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many different types of bird calls, I enjoy the variety of sounds they can make. There must be thousands species.